# How To Check Kernel Image Size?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Kindly tell me how to find size of the kernel image of Ubuntu that I installed on the Virtual Box.

Answer (score 5):

All Kernel image files are located in /boot. To find out which one you are currently using, run
`uname -r`

As en example, on my Xubuntu 12.04 machine, if I run

```
xuser@esr:/boot$ uname -r
3.2.0-53-generic
```

Now, to check in /boot:

```
xuser@esr:/boot$ ls -lha /boot | grep 3.2.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 782K Aug 23 00:13 abi-3.2.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 145K Aug 23 00:13 config-3.2.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M Sep  9 16:46 initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 2.2M Aug 23 00:13 System.map-3.2.0-53-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.7M Aug 23 00:13 vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic
```

As you can see, my kernel image file is called vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic is 4.7 MB big. The initial RAM disk it loads has 14 MB.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the size in MB of the full set if you run it on the terminal:

```
du -cm /lib/modules/$(uname -r) /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /boot/System.map-$(uname -r) /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```